# Transform XAML to C#

Tags: c#, xaml

I did not find it on the Internet
Help rewrite this code to C#

```
<Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True" >
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <TextBlock/>
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

My code
An error in the code takes off.

```cs
Style GroupStyle = new Style() { TargetType = typeof(GroupItem) }; 
                Setter setter = new Setter { Property = Control.TemplateProperty };
                ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate { TargetType = typeof(GroupItem) };
                var expander = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Expander));
                expander.SetValue(Expander.IsExpandedProperty, false);
                expander.SetValue(Expander.HeaderProperty, new TextBlock { }); // Error: System.NotSupportedException
                expander.SetValue(Expander.ContentProperty, new ItemsPresenter());
                template.VisualTree = expander;
                setter.Value = template;
                GroupStyle.Setters.Add(setter);
```

Doing datagrid grouping

Comment: *An error in the code takes off.* ? If you get an error, show the error.

Comment: Try `Style GroupStyle = new Style() { TargetType = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Controls.GroupItem") }`

Comment: @jps During program execution, the error on the first line is System.ArgumentNullException

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetType_System_String_

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @arconaut has said, first line should use `typeof`. So first tree lines are:

```cs
Style GroupStyle = new Style() { TargetType = typeof(GroupItem) }; 
Setter setter = new Setter { Property = Control.TemplateProperty };
ControlTemplate template = new ControlTemplate { TargetType = typeof(GroupItem) };
```

Then I believe `IsExpandedProperty` should be set to `True` based on the above XAML.

```cs
expander.SetValue(Expander.IsExpandedProperty, true);
```

Finally you need to pass `FrameworkElementFactory` as argument for `SetValue()` in the last two lines.

```cs
expander.SetValue(Expander.HeaderProperty, 
                  new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock)));
expander.SetValue(Expander.ContentProperty, 
                  new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ItemsPresenter)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your first line with this:

```
Style GroupStyle = new Style() { TargetType = typeof(GroupItem) };
```

The `x:Type` markup extension has a similar function to the `typeof()` operator in C#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xtype-markup-extension

Comment: Thank you, I replaced in 1 and 3 lines, but now the problems are on line 6. Error: System.NotSupportedException: "Invalid value" System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock "for" FrameworkElementFactory.SetValue ". Visual or ContentElement-derived values are not supported."

Comment: I believe the "Header" property only accepts a string: `expander.SetValue(Expander.HeaderProperty, "This is the header")`

Comment: Yes, it works, but I don't know how to fill it with data by which they are grouped